# Would need a little bit of clarification

Tags: java

Can you guys, please, explain to me what does `count[word.charAt(i)]++`, exactly do in this code and `overall--`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String S = "Some random text to test.";
    int count[] = new int[124];
    for (int i=0; i< S.length(); i++) {
       count[S.charAt(i)]++;
       System.out.print(count[S.charAt(i)] + " ");
    }
    int max = 1;
    char result = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
        if (max < count[S.charAt(i)] && S.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            max = count[S.charAt(i)];
            result = S.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The printing of `count[S.charAt(i)]` was just me trying to figure it out.

Comment: The `count[]` array is being used as a map of sorts, to keep track of how many times each character in `S` occurs.  This is just a hint.  If you step through your code and poke around, you'll see this.

Comment: It might be better here to use `128` instead of `124`, since otherwise for `|`, `}` and `~` this will produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

`S.charAt(i)` returns the character in the `i-th` position of that **string S**.

Then `count[S.charAt(i)]` will execute like this. Lets say you get 'S' as the character. Then the character value for 'S' will be 83. So, it will take the element of the 83 index in **count array** and increment it by one.

Answer (score 0):

`word.charAt(i)` returns the character at the **i-th index** in the **String `word`**.

`count` is an `int` array with **all zeros** automatically : `int count[] = new int[124];`

`count[i]++` increments the value that is in `count` at index **i** by 1.

Here, you're passing `word.charAt(i)` as an index i.e `count[word.charAt(i)]++`, and what it does is:

-Evaluate `word.charAt(i)` first, but 
note that **index i must be an integer!**
so automatically gets the **ASCII** value of the character. For example ('a' = 97, 'b' = 98..)

-then, `count[ASCII number returned]++`, for example `count[97]++`, will be incremented and now `count[97] = 1`

But note that if your **String** has '}', there will be **Index out of bound exception**, since its **ASCII** value is 125; and `125 > 124` the **size of count**!